# What is the difference between что-то, нечто и кое-что?

Tags: словоупотребление, местоимения

I know they can all be translated as *something*, and I know that **что-то** differs from **что-нибудь** in that it refers to something concrete, but not mentioned (whereas the former refers to anything at all) - but that's *all* I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`что-то` would be normally used when the speaker has no knowledge of what the object is, e.g.:

```
кажется, я что-то вижу - I think I see something
что-то не так - something is not right
```

`что-нибудь` would be used to name one unknown item that belongs to a category/set:

```
дай мне что-нибудь [выпить] - give me something [to drink] - from a set of drinks
```

`что-нибудь` also replaces `что-то` in questions:

```
- Ты что-нибудь видишь? - Do you see anything?
- Да, что-то вижу - Yes, I see something
```

`кое-что` is generally synonymous to `что-то`, but can be used to express eagerness on the part of the speaker:

```
- У меня кое-что для тебя есть! - I have something for you!
```

`нечто` is a deprecated form of `что-то`, but now has an additional meaning of surprise/excitement, in this meaning it can be translated as `thing`:

```
- Это нечто удивительное! - This is [something] wonderful! / This is a wonderful thing!

- Он просто нечто - He's just so cool/great (colloquial)
```

Comment: Usually, 'кое-что' implies that: (1) the speaker knows certainly for what it stands (usage of 'что-то' may mean that the speaker is uncertain); (2) the speaker is withholding this information. For example: 'Приходи к нему в гости, у него будет кое-что вкусное!' - 'Come visit him, there will be something delicious! [I know what it is, but won't tell]'. 'Приходи к нему в гости, у него будет что-то вкусное!' - 'Come visit him, there will be something delicious! [He said so, I don't know the particulars]'.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то = simply "something"

I spotted something.

Нечто = **something** in bold. Something surprising, unexpected, stunning.

I spotted **something**.

Кое-что = something I know what but will not say.

I spotted something, but this is secret.